# How to see if checkbox is toggled and perform action according to that, in datatables using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-checkboxes

I have a button which I need to be hidden or visible based on whether any checkbox in my dataTable is checked or not,

```
<input type = "submit" id = "update-button" class = "ml-5 btn btn-warning" value = "Update Selected" style = "color: white" hidden>
```

I am using these two for the checkbox in my Datatable

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.12/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js"></script>
```

I have now defined my DataTable like this,

```
var table = $("#classroom_teachers_table").DataTable({
      "processing": true, 
      "paging": true,
      "serverSide": true, 
      "info": false,
      "ajax": {
        url: "action.php", 
        method: "POST", 
        data: {action: "get_classroom_teachers"},
      },
      'columnDefs': [
         {
            'targets': 0,
            'checkboxes': {
               'selectRow': true
            }
         }
      ],
      'select': {
         'style': 'multi'
      },
      'order': [[1, 'asc']]
      
    });
```

What I want now is to check whether any checkbox is clicked or not... That is, I want to make an "on" function whenever a **checkbox** is clicked by the user. That function will then check the number of checkboxes ticked in the datatable. If the number is greater than 0, it will **display the input button** (by removing hidden attribute) and if not then it will change the attribute hidden to true...

But I don't get that **on what should I call this function?**
like,

```
$("#classroom_teachers_table tbody).on("click", function(){ 

*function*

)};
```

What should I write instead of *#classroom_teachers_table tbody* so that this function is called only when the checkbox is clicked/unclicked?

And also, can I do it within my table? Instead of a creating a completely new Jquery function?

Comment: Note that you are missing a `"` in `$("#classroom_teachers_table tbody).on("click", function(){` after `#classroom_teachers_table tbody`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes, thank you for correcting it. I have used it only as an example however to explain what I want to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you right, this is what your looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      'ajax': 'https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/arrays_id.json',
      'columnDefs': [
         {
            'targets': 0,
            'checkboxes': {
               'selectRow': true,
               'selectCallback': function(nodes, selected) {
                  
                  var rows_selected = table.column(0).checkboxes.selected();
                  if(rows_selected.length > 0) $("#update-button").show();
                  else $("#update-button").hide();
               }
            }
         }
      ],
      'select': 'multi',
      'order': [[1, 'asc']]
   });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.10/css/dataTables.checkboxes.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.10/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js"></script>

<input type="submit" id="update-button" class="ml-5 btn btn-warning" value="Update Selected" style="color: white; display: none;">
<br><br>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Extn</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Note:** For some reason the **hidden** attribute is not working in the Code Snippet, so I had to use the **CSS display** property, in order to show/hide your button.